# ROM for Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

So I'm looking to buy a nice phone but I don't want to spend the money to buy just a Microsoft or Android phone.

Are there any phones that can be imaged to be either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer is **No** . Reasons for this **No** :

1. It is not just OS that matters, there are hardware drivers as well to make sure the SoC works well with the rest of components. So you'll need those extra drivers alongside with OS if you want to run the OS on a different handset.
2. There is no official Windows 10 Mobile ROM that can be deployed to any phone. Also Android ROMs available are specific for a handset/group of handsets.
3. Even if there is a handset that can accept both OS's it will not be that easy you're imagining. An example is Alcatel Idol 4 handset which was first launched with android. The company had to make many changes to it to make it W10M-ready. Alike Appearance, yes, alike architecture, no.

That would be great not only for you but for everyone that an ideal phone exists
which can be configured to run any OS by simple flashing process but it is too good to be real. You'll be listening it in news when a thing of this kind will happen so get back and relax until then :). Hopefully that helps you consider buying a handset that can run only one OS. :)